# Space inside Bootstrap button on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this weird case because my bug displays differently at my website and at JSFiddle. That's why I also put a printscreen to show you how it looks on my website.
Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Pysilla/cm8s1d7t/

```html
<section id="fashion" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="item element col-md-5">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Fashion<span> photos</span></h2>
                </div>
                <p>Betiam finibus ac tellus sed ullamcorper. Suspendisse vestibulum mollis feugiat. Fusce vel turpis vitae nulla ullamcorper gravida non vel dolor. Ut rhoncus, metus vitae ultrices varius, ex mauris sodales leo, quis imperdiet turpis ipsum et ante. Phasellus hendrerit rutrum tincidunt. Sed sed viverra ligula, non ullamcorper mauris. Quisque dignissim sollicitudin nulla quis tincidunt. Cras at elementum massa. Cras eget mi hendrerit, congue nunc in, tristique massa. Vivamus at vestibulum ex.</p>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span>See more</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

(When you change size of screen you could see little stripe on the left inside of the button)

I hope you could see the difference.

[image: print screen]

Comment: That's quite curious. A quick fix would be for the .btn-primary:before {} css, instead of translateX(-100%) put translateX(-101%).

Comment: That was the first thing I have done when I saw this bug. Unfortunatelly doesn't work at my website. Maybe something in layout is cousing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to account for the `2px` border on `.btn-primary`. You can use `translate(calc(-100% - 2px));` on the hidden state of the pseudo element.

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.btn-primary{
    margin-top:1em;
    background-color:#3CD3DC;
    background-image:none;
    border:2px solid #3CD3DC;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    position:relative;
}
.btn-primary:hover{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #3CD3DC;
}
.btn-primary:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#1fa5ad;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform:translateX(calc(-100% - 2px));
    transition: 0.8s;
}
.btn-primary:hover:before{
    transform:translateX(0%);
    left:0;
}
.btn-primary span{
    position:relative;
}
</style>

    <section id="fashion" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="item element col-md-5">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Fashion<span> photos</span></h2>
                </div>
                <p>Betiam finibus ac tellus sed ullamcorper. Suspendisse vestibulum mollis feugiat. Fusce vel turpis vitae nulla ullamcorper gravida non vel dolor. Ut rhoncus, metus vitae ultrices varius, ex mauris sodales leo, quis imperdiet turpis ipsum et ante. Phasellus hendrerit rutrum tincidunt. Sed sed viverra ligula, non ullamcorper mauris. Quisque dignissim sollicitudin nulla quis tincidunt. Cras at elementum massa. Cras eget mi hendrerit, congue nunc in, tristique massa. Vivamus at vestibulum ex.</p>
                    <div class="text-center">
            <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span>See more</span></a>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Also doesn't work. I think that can be something with the width of the column it is in. When button takes full available place there is no problem but when I put it in col-md-5 I can see this gap on hover like on printscreen.

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna please reproduce the problem for me.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by reproduce?

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna you said "but when I put it in col-md-5 I can see this gap on hover like on printscreen." - give me a demo of that if you'd like me to try and fix it.

Comment: but it's the same situation like in jsfiddle and on printscreen in my main post.

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna I don't understand. Does the code in my post work here on stack overflow?

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna well, we can't really help if we cant reproduce the problem. All we can do is guess.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, I thought the issue was in the code I posted. Thank you.

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna it's not a bother, I want to help but can't if you can't reproduce the actual problem. Can you link to your site or include the additional code?

Comment: Sure! I'm still learning and working on my site but I put it on github that you could see it. Take a look at both fashion and food photos section. I realized  just after uploading I didn't change the position of a button in last section so don't check this section. https://jskrajna.github.io/photographer-site/

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna it has something to do with the `border-radius` creating a small gap on the edge. Curving can create artifacts like that. One fix would be to change `.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: transparent;` to `.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #1fa5ad;`

Comment: I thought about it before, but actually it looks worse than with transparent. But still it's some kind of solution :) Thanks

Comment: @JustynaSkrajna it looks as expected to me. here's what you have now http://i.imgur.com/wcZ4UZD.png and here is with the background color change http://i.imgur.com/dUeXqmZ.png

Comment: sure, but when it is animated the background should be transparent, and then button fills from left to right with color. In your solution button is already colored and then it fills with darker blue color. (Check this on jsfiddle)

Comment: try changing your `.btn-primary:hover {}` to this `.btn-primary:hover {
    animation: background .8s linear forwards;
    border: 2px solid #3CD3DC;
}` and add `@keyframes background { 0% {
    background: transparent;
}
style.css:28
99% {
    background: transparent;
}
style.css:31
100% {
    background: #1fa5ad;
} }`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set the button's :before element visibility to "hidden" by default and then "visible" on mouse over.

```
.btn-primary:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#1fa5ad;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    transition: 0.8s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-primary:hover:before{
    transform:translateX(0%);
    left:0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cm8s1d7t/1/

Comment: You won't belive it but it's still not right on my website. Like I commented before seems like the issue is deeper and probably something in the layout is cousing this bug. Thank you for help anyway.